# changing design of the activity while running

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

if I want to change the design of an TableLayout for example in the main.xml and add a TableRow or something, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate the TableRow and call [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) on the TableLayout (which you can access with [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)).